# Spring-data CustomConversions

Tags: spring-data

```
   public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DocumentType.StringToDocumentTypeConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new CustomConversions(converterList);
```

Its working fine in spring-data 2

now I m migrating spring data to 4.x

how to create CustomConversions object?

Answer (score 0):

`CustomConversions` lives in `org.springframework.data.convert`. That said, there is no Spring Data 4 (yet), i.e. it's a bit unclear what you're doing in the first place.

Comment: spring-data-couchbase